# How to format a date in Visual Basic?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

In Visual Basic, I have an object with an ItemDate key in it with the value being assigned to a label in ASPX. Here is the code:

```
lblItemDate.Text = .ItemDate
```

The result on the front end is '2021/11/15'. I want the result to be: 'November 15, 2021'

What do I need to do in Visual Basic to make the result on the front end be 'November 15, 2021' instead of '2021/11/15'?

In another VB file, the ItemDate object key is created this way:

```
oItem.ItemDate = Trim(odbcReader("ItemDate").ToString)
```

Comment: You mean *other* than the `Format()` function?

Comment: @RBarryYoung Can you write out the Format() function as an answer? I'm new to VB and don't know what that is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you really have a .Net DateTime struct:

```
lblItemDate.Text = .ItemDate.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy")
```

Otherwise you have a string, in which case you want to parse into a .Net DateTime struct so you can use the same ToString() call above:

```
Dim MyDate As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact( .ItemDate, "yyyy/MM/dd") 
lblItemDate.Text = MyDate.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy")
```

Even better if you can update your code so `ItemDate` is a DateTime value in the first place, and the `Parse()` call is moved to the point where the object is first created.

It's been a while, so I don't recall whether the `.ItemDate` shortcut is available in the context of a function call. You may need to use the full version of the variable name.

Comment: I get this error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.IFormatProvider'.

Comment: This is how it is created in another VB file: 

```
oItem.ItemDate = Trim(odbcReader("ItemDate").ToString)
```

Comment: What should I change 'Trim(odbcReader("ItemDate").ToString)' to to get 'lblItemDate.Text = .ItemDate.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy")' working?

Comment: `odbcReader("ItemDate")` is a date? Don't ToString it; cast it to a DateTime and assign it to ItemDate

Comment: @CaiusJard I'm new with VB. How would I cast it to a date?

Comment: First, you have to change whatever type `oItem` is to declare a `DateTime` rather than a `String` for the `ItemDate` field. Then you remove the `Trim()` and `ToString()` calls and use `DirectCast()` instead: `oItem.ItemDate = DirectCast(odbcReader("ItemDate"), DateTime)`

Comment: @CaiusJard I get this error when I take out the ToString and put in the answer above: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.IFormatProvider'.

Comment: If you're new with VB, perhaps you need to do your DB access at not quite such a low level. I don't think it will help you learn because it's hard to see the wood for the trees. What is the type of the ItemDate column in your database table?

Answer (score 0):

Besides the .Net functions mentioned in another answer, which work across different languages, there is also the [Format(..)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.format?view=net-5.0) function traditionally included with professional implementations of BASIC since the early 70's (I first used it in DEC's BASIC-Plus in 1976).

To get 'November 15, 2021' you'd do it like this:

```
lblItemDate.Text = Format(.ItemDate, "MMMM d, yyyy")
```